# Bind optionsText to property with an array of objects using Knockout?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, knockout.js

I have an array of objects stored inside an `observableArray` in Knockout.js, and I'm trying to bind one of the properties of the objects to the `optionsText` binding for a `select` element, however, this isn't working an the options are not being displayed.

The observableArray is initially blank and is populated by a AJAX request:

```
self.currentPeople = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Following the AJAX request, I can `console.log` this and receive the following back:

```
console.log(self.currentPeople);
// Produces [Object, Object] where each of the objects have properties of `personId` and `personName`
```

Yet my select dropdown remains unpopulated:

```
<select class="large-3" data-bind="options: currentPeople, optionsText: 'personName', optionsValue: 'personId', optionsCaption: 'All',  value: currentPerson"></select>
```

Only the 'All' appears. Any ideas?

Comment: how are you filling the currentPeople  array?

Comment: Populated via AJAX. It's assigned and I can `console.log` the variable to see it is populated.

Comment: Yes, I know. But in your code, you have self.currentPeople(ajaxData) or self.currentPeople = ajaxData ? It is a common mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `console.log(self.currentPeople)` shows your array of objects, that means you're (incorrectly) populating it using assignment instead of calling it as a function.

Populate it as:

```
self.currentPeople(newData);
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that.